# How to update Shiny App at every whole minute

Tags: r, shiny

How do I make a Shiny app update every *whole* minute?

Below is a modified version of the [Shiny timer example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/timer.html). The modified version only shows the time, and only updates every 60 seconds:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2(textOutput("currentTime"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$currentTime <- renderText({
    invalidateLater(1000*60, session)
    format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When run, the app might show:

```
10:41:07
10:42:07
10:42:07
```

Instead, I would like it to show:

```
10:41:07
10:42:00
10:43:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tada

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h2(textOutput("currentTime"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    next_whole <- lubridate::ceiling_date(Sys.time(), "10 seconds")
    print(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"))
    go_singal <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

    first_check <- observe({
        invalidateLater(1000)
        req(next_whole - Sys.time() < 0)
        go_singal(TRUE)
        first_check$destroy()
        print("destroy")
    })

    output$currentTime <- renderText({
        if(!go_singal()) return(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"))
        invalidateLater(10*1000, session)
        print(format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"))
        format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

# [1] "11:30:21"
# [1] "destroy"
# [1] "11:30:30"
# [1] "11:30:40"
```

The trick here is we use another `invalidateLater` to check the time before the first whole time.

1. Use `lubridate` to find out the next whole minute.
2. Calculate how long do we need to wait till the next whole minute.
3. If we haven't reached that minute, keep waiting, nothing happens, but still check every second.
4. If the time comes, trigger a `go_singal` flag so `renderText` can be run every one minute.
5. Destroy the "every-one-second-check" (`first_check`), because it is expensive and we no longer need it.

In my example, I use every 10s, in your case change to `lubridate::ceiling_date(Sys.time(), "1 minute")` and `invalidateLater(60*1000, session)`